# php mysql fixed value for ratio button to get all status

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have form field with ratio button. as my mysql database my all data row has a column named status where values like 1, 2, 3 etc.
I have table `status_details` from where get all status value.
[image]

To get status, my form has ratio button which specify the status. I want all data whatever its status is.
 as for I make the form field like that : 
what will be value for the ratio button "All".
actually under all button i want get all 1- 6 values.
so that , i can get data from another table where status like 1-6  not only like 1 or 2 or 3

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleId">Status</label>
    <div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" name="status" value="1" checked>All</label>
        <?php
        $table = "status_details";
        $order = "ASC";
        $column = "name";
        $datas = getTableDataByTableName($table, $order, $column);
        foreach ($datas as $data) {
            ?>
            <label><input type="radio" name="status" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>"><?php echo $data->name; ?></label>
        <?php } ?>


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is actual question ? you want all data of what ? value of radio button "All" is 1, its hardcoded in html

Comment: actually under all button i want get all 1- 6 values.
so that , i can get data from another table where status like 1-6  not only like 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: oh i got it now, you can specify whatever value for "All" option, for example "all", in the php you just check if the value of `$_POST['status'] == 'all'` is equal to that special value and if so you change the sql query to not having something like `WHERE status = `

Comment: than what will be the query for that like : 
$status  = $_POST['status'];
 //query from db
 $resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM rlp_info WHERE rlp_status = $status );

Comment: like this: `$resultSet = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM rlp_info WHERE rlp_user_id = $member".($status!='all'?" AND rlp_status = $status":'')." AND request_date BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate'");`

Comment: wow, its work. thank you

Comment: yea because `$status='all'` is not the same as `$status!='all'` which means if the variable status is *not* equal to 'all'